# When i start the application json changes doesnt change

Tags: python, json, list

I am trying to build a python program that prompts the user for numbers to take from a list. It runs correctly and when running it removes the numbers from the json. But when i restart the application, json comes back with all the numbers in the list.
This is my code. I am also open to hear another easier ways to do it. Thank you
Thank you.

```
import json

album = []
signal = 0

print("")
for i in range(1, 351):
    album.append(i)


while signal != 1:
    numero = int(input("Number to take from list"))
    for n in range(len(album)-1):
        if numero == album[n]:
            album.remove(album[n])
    if numero == 350:
        album.remove(album[349])
    if numero == -1:
        senal = 1
        print(album)
    print(album)

json_string = json.dumps(album, indent=4)
with open('album.json', 'w') as file:
    file.write(json_string)
print(json_string)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the sample inputs, the expected outputs and the actual outputs.  One item I noticed is that is ```signal``` is never set to ```1```.  So does your script actually end (without ctrl-c)?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is always reset when you restart your program because you are not loading `album.json`. You must check if `album.json` already exists, then load it into album at the beginning of the program, and if it does not exist, then create it, like you code already does.